# How to achieve dynamic fair processing between batch tasks?

Tags: batch-processing, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis

Our use case is that our system supports scheduling multiple multi-channel send jobs at any time. Multi-channel send meaning send emails, send notifications, send sms etc.

How it currently works is we have a SQS queue per channel. Whenever a job is scheduled, it pushes all its send records to appropriate channel SQS. Any job scheduled later then pushes its own send records to appropriate channel SQS and so on. This leads to starvation of later scheduled jobs if the first scheduled job is high volume, as its records will be processed first from queue before reaching 2nd job records.

On consumer side, we have much lower processing rate than incoming as we can only do a fixed amount of sends per hour. So a high volume job could go on for a long time after being scheduled.

To solve the starvation problem, our first idea was to create 3 queues per channel, low, medium high volume and jobs would be submitted to queue as per their volume. Problem is if 2 or more same volume jobs come, then we still face this problem.

The only guaranteed way to ensure no starvation and fair processing seems like having a queue per job created dynamically. Consumers process from each queue at equal rate and processing bandwidth gets divided between jobs. High volume job might take long time to complete, but it wont choke processing for other jobs.

We could create the sqs queues dynamically for every job scheduled, but that will mean monitoring maybe 50+ queues at some point. Better choice seemed having a kinesis stream with multiple shards, where we would need to ensure every shard only contains single partition key that would identify a single job, I am not sure if that's possible though.

Are there any better ways to achieve this, so we can do fair processing and not starve any job?
If this is not the right community for such questions, please let me know.